# how to write data to a file using azure function in azure data factory

Tags: azure, function

I have a file(employee_details.csv) in azure data lake storage gen2 location which is a blank file .I have requirement to store only the current datetime to the content of file. But I am unable to find any inbuilt component available in azure data factory for the same. Hence I am thinking to use azure function for the same but I am new to azure function .Can you please guide me in how to achieve the same using azure function ?

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is to store just some value (date in your case), you can easily store orchestrate the flow in ADF. Based on your question it seems you have the orchestration ready and have troubles storing using ADF.

You can often use the Copy Activity to store data. For instance,

Here I have extracted the ids in a variable.

[image]

1. You can have an empty CSV file as the source.
2. Add Additional Column (date in your case) and store the value as your variable
3. Set Sink as the CSV dataset where you want to store the file (use pipeline parameters to make it dynamic if needed)

[image]

Edit -

The empty File Dataset -
[image]

The writing to file dataset -
[image]

You need to have an empty file created.
[image]
How this works is that it read the empty file, adds a column with values - variable ids and copies it at sink.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above approach but nothing is getting written to the copied file.

Comment: I have added more information in the edit. Can you please try that?

Comment: I understand what you are doing but what I want is only the utcnow() value in the sink destintation file and nothing else in that file(no headers, no other data and no quotes etc.) just only the value of utcnow(). The source csv file is absolutely blank and the destination csv file will only have utcnow()

Comment: You will need to add some sort of formatter to convert your datetime object to string. Like - 
@{formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm.ss')}

But yes, you might get inverted quotes in the final file along with a header column.

Answer (score 1):

An Azure Function has a lot overhead for such a simple use case.  Nonetheless, the function below worked for me when triggered from an ADF pipeline. For the function to work, its managed identity must be enabled and granted write access to the output file - either via RBAC or ACL's. A production version of this function would need error handling, parameterization, etc.  Deploying the function in Azure is well-documented, so I have not addressed it here.

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import datetime
from azure.identity import ChainedTokenCredential,ManagedIdentityCredential
import os, uuid, sys
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:    

    MSI_credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()
    credential_chain = ChainedTokenCredential(MSI_credential)
    client = DataLakeServiceClient(
               https://<your-storage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
               credential = credential_chain)

    # Create file
    file_client = client.get_file_client(
                    file_system = "<your-adlsgen2-container>",
                    file_path = "<your-timestamp-file")
    file_client.create_file()

    # Write current timestamp to file
    current_date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    file_content = current_date_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %S %p")
    file_client.append_data(data=file_content, offset = 0)
    file_client.flush_data(len(file_content))

    return func.HttpResponse("Ok", status_code=200)
```